# Should integration tests span across solutions

Tags: azure, architecture, integration-testing, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

I have an inherited a Windows Azure based application which consists primarily of 2 parts - an API server (implemented as a Web role) and a Worker (implemented of course as a Worker role). Both these parts have their independent solutions in Visual Studio.

The API server exposes endpoints which can be used to configure 'tasks' that are saved into the database. The Worker picks up these tasks from the database and executes them.

An integration test that tests the entire workflow of calling the endpoints to create the task and the worker executing these tasks, is written in the API server solution. Of course for the test to pass the worker needs to be running.

I am not comfortable with the fact that I need to run the worker in order for the tests in the API server to pass.

Question - how do I write integration tests for such a setup? Was it a mistake in the first place to have 2 independent solutions for the roles instead of having all in one solution?

Comment: Unfortunately there's really no single (or right) answer to this, either from the testing standpoint or the overall architecture (separate solutions vs single solution). Lots of consideration when thinking through how to divide components, and we really don't have any background info on this project (nor would it really be a stackoverflow-style thing to have an open discussion about it here).

Comment: Also: The topic of testing is (in my opinion) separate from the topic of architecture. (I still see both as too-broad and opinion-based for stackoverflow, but as you work through more detailed, objective questions to ask, I think you should consider keeping these separate.)